# Dependent drop down list for multiple cells, how

Tags: google-sheets

Currently automating more of my budgeting google sheet, and thus implementing the dependent drop down list!

For example in my **Lists Tab below**, I have named the cell range from B6:B19 as Housing, B20:B26 as Food and so on
[image: Lists Tab]

> I wanted to ask if there is a way to duplicate the function of the
> cells drop-down lists to multiple cells? or do they need to be done
> individual rows, which is going to be cumbersome?

Such that I can have it as part of my Expenses Tab to keep track of recurring expenses
[image: Expenses tab with duplicated dependent drop down]

Comment: If I understand correctly you would like to select one category from the first column and then expect the second column to only list expenses from said category? 
Are you familiar with [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)? Would that work for your case?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, For example, I would like to select Any of the categories available (Food, Housing, Entertainment, other, etc.) and for example, I selected Food, then I want to see only the "Types of Expenses" under the Food category, which can be Groceries, Dish cleaning, restaurants etc.

Comment: Now I know this can be done for 1 cell, using the `INDIRECT` function and cell named ranges, but how to duplicate the same thing over multiple cells as you see in my second picture of the question?

Comment: Also I am not familiar with Apps script

Comment: How have you done this for only one cell?

Comment: I simply followed this tutorial on Youtube (https://youtu.be/AUM6s-hbX6w) and used INDIRECT FUNCTION, named cell ranges and Data Validation to do it for 1 cell

Comment: Do a Google search for Sheets and Cascading Dropdown.  You'll find a few very good examples, like these two, which should be perfect for you:                            https://www.bpwebs.com/dependent-drop-down-list-in-google-sheet/         https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/dynamic-dependent-drop-down-list-in-google-sheets/

Comment: There are some older answers on SO that involve scripts, like this: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/6735222?hl=en        Also, I would suggest that you consider adding the term "cascading dropdowns" to your question title, which might help people searching on this topic.

Comment: I think the correct way to handle this could be through Apps Script in case you would be down for that kind of solution. Other options see too convoluted.